# An example of javascript__dopostback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Please provide an example of calling the `__doPostBack` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are some simple links to calling `__doPostBack`

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

`http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function` (copy and paste this link, it renders incorrectly in the markup)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at "Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function" : http://aspalliance.com/895